# Need multiple IPs on one computer for testing chat application

Tags: java, windows, video, ip, chat

I am making a chat Software using Java, so I want to test it on two or more  different computers (IP's to be specific). But I have a single PC only. I can't take my app again and again to my friend's house during it's development. Please tell a way so that I can have 2 or more IP's on a single PC for checking whether it works fine or not.
After the chat i want to add a video conferencing feature to it, so having more than one IP is a must (probably). So please suggest some way.
**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First idea, you can use virtualbox. Install OS on Virtualbox. After then
if you have router, then you and virtualbox have different IP address

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to set up multiple IP addresses on a computer:

1. To have multiple network interface cards (NICs) on your computer and to assign a different IP address to each card.
2. To assign multiple IP addresses to a single NIC.
3. To combine 2 previous options: have multiple NICs with multiple IPs assigned to one or more of them.

Look here:
http://www.loadtestingtool.com/help/how-setup-ip.shtml

Comment: I think this is the best answer because then you don't have to deal with the overhead of running 1 whole VM per IP, which can get expensive, fast. Getting more than one IP per interface in linux is dead easy.

Comment: Will There be any loss of speed in Internet ? I dont want 2 loose any Speed coz  after installing Vm v have 2 go for Prxy or VPN to change IP. If i follow THIS ANSWER will there be no  loss in internet speed ?  @m.aibin

Comment: no, because you will have two private addresses on the NIC. It will be internally, without accessing Internet.

Comment: So  @ m.aibin according to u if i go with option 2 , I will have 2 different IPs without loss of internet speed . Here by IP i mean the IP other than this one 192.168.1.1(What it is called public or private don't remember). So will i get 2 different IP like 29.136.65.23 and 27.165.43.98  ?? is it so ??

Comment: no, you can't get two public IPs (example 29.136.65.23). Public IP is from your Internet Service Provider, so you can't add more. You can get multiple private IPs, but there are still different IPs (example 192.168.1.1)

Comment: and you can use private IPs to test your app.

Comment: You can get almost infinite private IPs if you use IPv6 btw and fyi

Answer (score 3):

For having two or more IP addresses on a single interface, you could make use of the `netsh` command that comes along with MS Windows. [Here](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc731521(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_addaddress) is a link to the documentation for adding an address to an interface. The command you need would imo be similar to

```
netsh interface ipv4 add address “Local Area Connection” 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Is there a equivalent for linux?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to just use a DM with an IP that you made up, and later on when everything is working as expected change it to the real thing and do testing on more than one computer.